# Google Place Api Prediction class cast to Position or something equivalent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-places-api

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project. I have a very simple page where a job seeker searches job posts by entering a location(ex. New York) and a radius(picker). I have the following code in my PageViewModel:

```
public class SearchPageViewModel : BaseViewModel

    {

        private readonly INavigation _navigation;

        private readonly GooglePlacesApiService _api;

        private IEnumerable<JobPost> Posts;
        public int RadiusIndex {get;set;}

        public SearchPageViewModel (INavigation navigation, IEnumerable<JobPost> posts)

        {

            _navigation = navigation;
            var settings = GoogleApiSettings.Builder.WithApiKey("MY_API_KEY").Build();
            _api = new GooglePlacesApiService(settings);
            this.posts =posts;

        }

        public ICommand DoSearchCommand

        => new Command(async () => await DoSearchAsync().ConfigureAwait(false), () => CanSearch);

        public ICommand SelectItemCommand

        => new Command<Prediction>(async (prediction) =>

        {

             //!!!Filter jobposts based on position and radius to be able to display it!!!

            _api.ResetSessionToken();

        });

        private string _searchText;

        public string SearchText
        {

            get => _searchText;

            set 
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref _searchText, value))

                    OnPropertyChanged("CanSearch");
            }

        }

        private List<Prediction> _results;

        public List<Prediction> Results

        {

            get => _results;

            set => SetProperty(ref _results, value);

        }



        public bool CanSearch => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchText) && SearchText.Length > 2;

        private async Task DoSearchAsync()

        {

            var results = await _api.GetPredictionsAsync(SearchText)

                                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if(results != null && results.Status.Equals("OK"))

            {

                ResultCount = results.Items.Count;

                Results = results.Items;

                OnPropertyChanged("HasResults");

            }

        }

    }

public class JobPost
{
    public Position Location {get;set;}
}
```

Ok, so far it works well. Once the search button is clicked the job seeker get a list of predictions and picks a place. But the problem is now, how do I get the positioning(longitude and latitude) of the picked prediction, so I can filter the job posts so I can dsiplay the result to the job seeker. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the Essentials Geocoding plugin - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?tabs=android#using-geocoding

Comment: @Jason thanks. But Prediction class is missing the adress property which is required by the geocodin getlocationsasync method

Comment: you should be able to pass a city or zip, you shouldn't have to use a specific street address

Comment: @Jason Sorry but I cant seem to see any of those you mentioned in the prediction class. And also, looking up by city can result in ambiguity if searces are made worldwide.

Comment: "how do I get the positioning(longitude and latitude) of the picked prediction" - you attempt to geocode the picked prediction.

Comment: @Jason Im fairly new to this. Maybe Im not seeing the obvious but it would be nice if you could tell me which method  to invoke and which  argumentet to pass.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Essentials [GeoCoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?tabs=android#using-geocoding) plugin

```
var address =  "New York";
var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(address);
```

`locations` will be a list of potential matches, each with a lat/long

```
var location = locations?.FirstOrDefault();
if (location != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
}
```

Comment: thanks,,  so  you are basically saying that I will retrieve the ponterial locations as you demonstrated  from the user  text input and then update the suggestion list with matches for the user  to pick one?

Comment: again, your question is "how do I get the positioning(longitude and latitude) of the picked prediction" - you would pass the user's picked prediction to GetLocationsAsync to get the lat/long for that location.  Generally if multiple results are return you should just select the first one, but you will have to test that to determine what works best for your use case.

Comment: "how do I get the positioning(longitude and latitude) of the picked prediction", but in you code you passing a string(adress)  variable to Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync which obviously is not  aGooglePlacesApi.Models. Prediction. I think I have to  continue to look deeper into the documentation. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: a cursory look at the Predictions docs shows that the Prediction model has a "Description" field that contains the location name you can pass to the Geocoder.

Comment: Yes! Now I got the result I needed. I sure did miss that property.  Thank you again for your time.